# Is there a way to know what jobs are currently running in a snakemake workflow?

Tags: snakemake

I have a snakemake workflow with 75 steps. Recently, I solved an issue where sometimes a step in the workflow was waiting on user input. When running the workflow just now, it seemed to be stuck, and I wasn't sure if it was a similar issue or if a newly added step just takes a long time. After scrolling through the console output, I decided to copy all of it into a text file and then came up with a one-liner to show me which jobs hadn't finished:

```
$ grep "Finished job " ~/Temporary/snakemake_console_output.txt | sort -k 3 -n | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | perl -e 'while(<>){/(\d+)/;$n=$1;if($l && $l+1 != $n){print("$l - $n\n")}$l=$n}'
56 - 62
64 - 68
```

However, some of these jobs had not started yet, so I kept working on it and found out which job was currently blocked:

```
$ grep -E "Finished job |^\s+jobid:" ~/Temporary/snakemake_console_output.txt | perl -e 'while(<>){if(/Finished job (\d+)/){push(@fin,$1)}elsif(/jobid: (\d+)/){$h->{$1}=0}}foreach my $fj (sort {$a <=> $b} @fin){$n=$fj;if($l && $l+1 != $n){foreach my $rj (($l+1)..($n-1)){print("$rj\n") if(exists($h->{$rj}))}}$l=$n}'
61
```

It turned out that it was an R script with some hefty installs from a recently added step. Is there a more straightforward way to do this without resorting to this "hackery"? I could do a `ps`, but many of the jobs use the same utilities, and it would involve opening up the rules files to figure out which rule it was from.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running through slurm, you can do some similar hackery with squeue or check out [reportseff](https://github.com/troycomi/reportseff).

For local execution, you could try a custom [shell prefix](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#i-want-to-configure-the-behavior-of-my-shell-for-all-rules-how-can-that-be-achieved-with-snakemake) to increment some global variable and decrement on completion.  Will probably run into a race condition or two though!

Built in, there's [this option](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/monitoring.html) but I can't vouch for it specifically.